# WebStorm, How can I edit templates in react-templates?

Tags: webstorm, react-templates

I use WebStorm and I have this plugin: https://github.com/idok/react-templates-plugin

Having it installed in my WebStorm I can type for example `rcls` and immediately have:

```
import React, {
    Component,
    PropTypes,
} from 'react';

class LocalizedText extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}

LocalizedText.propTypes = {};
LocalizedText.defaultProps = {};

export default LocalizedText;
```

I wonder if it is possible to find some file on my computer and make some changes (new lines and so on) manually?

Sorry if it's a silly question but I can't find the answer in google.

Comment: just installed this plugin (v. 1.1.1) - `rcls` does nothing to me. However, looks like it's a live template added by the plugin. You can look for it in Preferences | Editor | Live Templates, React Templates.

Comment: Thank you, Lena! Found it in Preferences | Editor | Live Templates, React Templates